Proof verification of inequality with infinite sum and integral
I am asked the following question: Prove/disprove:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{x \in X} \limsup_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{l=1}^{f(n)} a(l,n,m,x) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{x \in X}  \sum_{l=1}^{f(n)}\limsup_{m \rightarrow \infty} a(l,n,m,x).
$$
Additionally, let $a(\cdot) \geq 0$. It seems the inequality is straightforward since
$$
 \limsup_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{l=1}^{f(n)} a(l,n,m,x) \leq  \sum_{l=1}^{f(n)}\limsup_{m \rightarrow \infty} a(l,n,m,x).
$$ This follows by definition and the fact that $f(n)$ is some finite function of $n$. Moreover, since the inequality is true for each $n$ and $x$, we take the integral and infinite sum next, and the result follows. Is this correct ? I don't think the RHS needs to be convergent (since $a(\cdot) \geq 0$, even if it is divergent, the result will hold). Do I need to add any more explanation or condition?
